# Getting Specific checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, vb.net

I need to get my series of checked checkboxes without getting all the rest on the page so I'm trying to narrow down specifically but the following code does not seem to work.

```
$('#button').click(cc);
    function cc() {
        var va = [];
          $('input:checkbox[name=lpids]:checked').each(function(i){
            va.push(this.id);
          });
        alert(va);
    }
```

and

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="ck0" runat="server" name="lpids" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
```

Now I looked on up getting specific values and the above should work but I'm getting nothing.

EDIT:

```
<span name="lpids" class="chk"><input id="ck6" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ck6" /></span>
```

What I'm getting in source code.

Comment: How does the generated markup looks like

Comment: How do I get generated markup?

Comment: From the browser's context menu `View page source`

Comment: <span name="lpids" class="chk"><input id="ck6" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ck6" /></span> -- looks like that problem might be. ASP doing gen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what is generated, this should work

```
$('[name=lpids] [type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(i){
```

Comment: Yep that was it. Need to remember ASP.NET likes to generate names.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
this.id
```

try

```
$(this).attr('id')
```

Comment: No success with that attempt.

Comment: These lines do essentially the same, as `id` property of DOM Element is supported by all modern browsers (and even some ancient ones). I'd even say the first is preferable from the performance point, as it's a single property access versus two function calls.

Answer (score 0):

try this fiddle I just created and it pulls the id.  just add class="chk" to each checkbox...

http://jsfiddle.net/eformx/xENNa/

The guts...

```
$('#button').click(function () {

    $('.chk').each(function() {

        var checked = this.checked ? 'checked' : '';
        if (checked){
            var id = this.id;
            alert(id);
        }
    });


});
```

Comment: Yea, fixed that typo. Still same problem though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#button').click(cc);
    function cc() {
          $('input[name=lpids]:checked').each(function(){
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
          });
    }
```

Comment: No success with that. blank alert box. weird.